# Move an image upwards and downward loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using the following code to animate a sprite upwards and downwards.

```
Vector3 diff = bottomPos - scanImage.transform.localPosition  ;
int threshold = Convert.ToInt32(diff.y );
if ( threshold == 50)
{
    shouldMoveBottom = false;
}
else if(threshold== -50)
{
    shouldMoveBottom = true;
}
if (shouldMoveBottom)
{
    scanImage.localPosition = Vector3.SmoothDamp(scanImage.localPosition, bottomPos, ref buttonVelocity, smoothTime);
}
else
{
    scanImage.localPosition = Vector3.SmoothDamp(scanImage.localPosition, topPos, ref buttonVelocity, smoothTime);
}
```

My Top and bottom position are as follows,

```
Vector3 topPos = new Vector3(0, 50, 0);
Vector3 bottomPos = new Vector3(0, -50, 0);
```

For some reason, the movement just stops after the first time. what am I missing?

Comment: Is you goal to constantly move it up and down and up and down ... ?

Comment: yes, I would like to move it constantly up and down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather use [`Vector3.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) (+ optionally [`Mathf.SmoothStep`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothStep.html)) and as factor use any looping method that provides values between `0` and `1` like e.g. [`Mathf.PingPong`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html)

```
// Duration in seconds for one full cycle
[SerializeField] private float loopDuration = 1;

private float startTime;

private void Start()
{
    startTime = Time.time;
}

private void Update()
{
    var factor = Mathf.PingPong((Time.time - startTime) / (loopDuration * 0.5f), 1f);
    // optionally add ease-in and -out
    factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0f, 1f, factor);

    // will interpolate between both positions on the given factor
    scanImage.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(bottomPos, topPos, factor);
}
```

[image]

or simply `Mathf.Sin` as mentioned by [KYL3R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62995555/7111561).

You would however need a lot of calculation in order to make it configurable in the same way but then you can basically also use it together with the `Lerp`:

```
private void Update()
{
    var factor = (1 + Mathf.Sin((Time.time - startTime) * 2 * Mathf.PI / loopDuration)) / 2f;
    
    scanImage.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(bottomPos, topPos, factor);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `Mathf.PingPong` which is naturally smooth would be to use `Mathf.Sin`

```
private Vector3 _start;
private Vector3 _offset = Vector3.zero;

void Start () 
{
   _start = transform.position;
}

void Update()
{
    _offset.y = Mathf.Sin(Time.time); // multiply time to speed up / slow down. Multiply the result to scale the moving amplitude.
    transform.position = _start + _offset;
}
```

Comment: `Mathf.Sin` is actually a pretty good alternative! Note however that it is also slightly more difficult to calculate the correct values for it in order to configure it the same way as `PingPong` .. you would need to calculate it radians in order to match a certain loop duration ;) Not that it is an issue but worth mentioning I thought ;)

Comment: Good point. 2PI are a full circle in radians, so logic would be `Mathf.Sin(Time.time * (2 * Mathf.PI) * PingPongs) * amplitude` But I guess most programmers should be able to figure this out :)

Comment: Yes as said I find using `Mathf.Sin`  actually a very good solution .. it would just need these modifications in order to make it really usable ;)